# How do I change the margin for the second page in a PDF using iTextsharp?

Tags: itext

Is there a way to change the page margins for the second page in a PDF using iTextSharp?

I now have:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 144f, 72f, 144f, 90f);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

/* first page content */

document.NewPage();
document.SetMargins(72f, 72f, 72f, 100f);

/* second page content */
```

However, the margins on the second page are the ones set for the first page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Switch the two lines:

```
document.SetMargins(72f, 72f, 72f, 100f);
document.NewPage();
```

As documented, the NewPage() function performs a lot of initialisations, among others, setting the margins. So you need to change the margins BEFORE triggering a new page, not after.

Comment: How should I apply different margins to the pages based upon the page number?

Comment: @MdAshiff use `PdfPageEventHelper` and the function `onEndPage`, there are several answers here that explain that. In case you still need this, ask a question and I will gladly help.